# Jsoup get text from div class

Tags: android, html, jsoup

This my html

```
<div class="open-statuses">

  <div class="open-status" id="lifts-status-scripted">
    <h3>Lifts</h3>
    <div class="status-graph">
      <canvas width="177" height="177"></canvas>
      <div class="open-number">04</div>
      <div class="total-number">4</div>
    </div>
    <a href="/lifts-and-trails/" class="details">Details</a>
  </div>
  <div class="open-status" id="trails-status-scripted">
    <h3>Trails</h3>
    <div class="status-graph">
      <canvas width="177" height="177"></canvas>
      <div class="open-number">12</div>
      <div class="total-number">169</div>
    </div>
    <a href="/lifts-and-trails/" class="details">Details</a>
  </div>

  <div class="open-status open" id="road-status-scripted">
    <h3>Road</h3>
    <div class="status-graph">
      <canvas width="177" height="177"></canvas>
      <div class="status-message">Open</div>
    </div>
    <a href="/mountain-report/road-conditions/" class="road-conditions">Road Conditions</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the text from the (div class="open-status" id="trails-status-scripted"), I cant do it. I use this code for the first class, with no problems, but I can't do it for the second div class.

```
Elements div1=document.select("#mountain-report-page");
Elements div2=div1.select(".open-statuses-holder");
Elements div3=div2.select(".open-statuses");
Jliftbig = div3.select("div.open-number").first().ownText();
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. I resolved with this code

```
Element div = document.select("div[id=mountain-report-page] div[class=open-statuses-holder] div[class=open-statuses] div[class=open-status] ").get(2);
String Jtrails = div.select("div.open-number").first().ownText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify in this way:

```
Elements div = doc.select("div[id=mountain-report-page] div[class=open-statuses-holder] div[class=open-statuses] div[class=open-status]");

for (Element e : div){
    if (e.id().equals("trails-status-scripted")){
        Element ele = e.select("div[class=status-graph] div[class=open-number]").first();
        String str = ele.text();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use e.text(); and return an empty string. This is teh webpage http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/

Comment: still empty, return an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Since in HTML all IDs [must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page), so you can simply use this selector.

```
Element div = document.select("#trails-status-scripted .open-number");
```

**Notes:**

- `#foo` equals to `*[id=foo]`
- `.foo` equals to `*[class=foo]`